# INSTALL_SHORTCUT then enableComponent makes shortcut change on Android 4.2.2

Tags: android, android-intent, package

My problem is when I create a shortcut to my application and later enable or disable a component, the shortcut icon and name change on Android 4.2.2 but on 4.0 or 4.1 shortcut is OK.

```
public void createShortcut(Context context){
   Intent myLauncherIntent = new Intent();
   myLauncherIntent.setClassName("com.my.package"," com.my.package.MyActivity");
//or  Intent myLauncherIntent = new Intent(context,MyActivity.class); 
   myLauncherIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);      
   myLauncherIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   myLauncherIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);  

   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, myLauncherIntent);
   intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "name");          intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext( context,R.drawable.ic_my_shortcut) );
   intent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
   intent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
   context.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Later in my application if I use :

```
MyClass.enableComponent(getApplicationContext(), getPackageManager(), myAnotherActivity.class, true);
```

Then the shortcut previously created change with the default application icon and name. This only appears on Android 4.2.2
Any idea?

Comment: Did you solved this issue? here my question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22613320/intent-install-shortcut-creates-shortcut-in-the-second-page

Comment: Sorry but I don't have solved my problem.