# On Android 4.2.2, Intent INSTALL_SHORTCUT creates shortcut in the second page

Tags: android, android-intent, shortcut, android-4.2-jelly-bean, homescreen

I get a strange result when calling this code to simply create a shortcut in the home screen.

The shortcut **is created on the second page** of the home screen (and the first page is empty so there is enought space!). Any ideas?

```
public static void installShortcut(Context context, String packageName, String componentName, String shortcutName, Parcelable icon) {
    Intent shortcut = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(packageName, componentName);
    shortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).setComponent(cn));
    shortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, shortcutName);
    shortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, icon);
    shortcut.putExtra("duplicate", false);
    context.sendBroadcast(shortcut);
}

// gets some info from external package by name
public static void createShortcutForPackage(Context context, String packageName, String className) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, className));

    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    ResolveInfo ri = pm.resolveActivity(intent, 0);

    String shortcutName = ri.loadLabel(pm).toString();
    String activityName = ri.activityInfo.name;
    int iconId = ri.activityInfo.applicationInfo.icon;

    Context pkgContext;
    try {
        pkgContext = context.createPackageContext(packageName, Context.CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE | Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
        if (pkgContext != null) {
            ShortcutIconResource sir = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(pkgContext, iconId);
            installShortcut(pkgContext, packageName, activityName, shortcutName, sir);
        }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    }
}
```

This is the default Android 4.2.2 Home screen:

[image]

**UPDATE:**
On Android 4.0.4 the shortcut is created in the right place.

Comment: this second page is the default page ?

Comment: I hit the "home button" and then swipe to focus the next page, this is the second page (on the right of the home page)

Comment: so change your default page to first page instead of the second page

Comment: I'm little confused, how can I do?

Comment: from the launcher settings

Comment: Still not clear to me, I see action for setting the background image but nothing else, mybe I'm looking in the wrong place...

Comment: yes indeed, which launcher are you using ?

Comment: the default Android 4.2.2 home screen

Comment: Update: in Android 4.0.4 the shortcut is created in the right place...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are hundreds of home screen implementations, both pre-installed and ones installable via the Play Store. Each is welcome to either:

- ignore your `Intent` entirely, by simply not having an `<intent-filter>` for it, or
- put the shortcut wherever it wants

> On Android 4.0.4 the shortcut is created in the right place.

No, it is put in "the right place" in both cases, as it is the authors of the home screen -- not you -- who determines what "the right place" is.

Comment: Ok, now it's clear. So I can't do anything if I don't know how to set up the home screen installed in my low cost tablet.